# How do I position a div background-image absolute to the screen and not to the relative position of the div?

Tags: css

I have a div which background I want to position absolutely as the image has to align with the background image which is positioned absolutely to 0,0

```
    div{
      background-image: url(someImage.jpg);
      background-position: absolute 0px 0px; // either something like this or getting div's x & y values would help
    }
```

So this is the actual code
HTML

```
    <nav>
        <ul> 
            <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#projects">Projects</a></li>
            <li><a href="#Services">Services</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
    </nav>
```

css

```
        #header nav ul {
            background-image: url("../../images/bg.jpg");
            background-position:absolute 0 0; // this is the position which i would like to make absolute           
            background-repeat: no-repeat;       
        }
```

and this is what I'm trying to achieve
[image]

so nav Background is only shown in the NAV area, the problem is that NAV is vertical or horizontal depending screen size, and zoom, so it doesn't have a fixed position, but if the NAVbackground position was fixed (absolute positioning that would solve my problem)

Comment: You would position the div to try to line it up. The background that's on the div, there isn't much you can do with that

Comment: If you don't want your background image to be the background of the div, it sounds like you should put your background image in a different element.

Comment: problem is that my dive moves dinamically, I need its background to align with the background of the page itself, it would help if I could reference the div's position itself something as "background-position: -self.x -self.y;" or something like that

Comment: @JakeReece i do want my background image to be a part of the div, the image is larger than the div itself and the position of the background should be fixed

Comment: you should clarify your question with a snippet and dummy image to show your issue, so one can tell you if  you are using the wrong method and if any other can be used. ` background-position: absolute 0px 0px;` would be background-position + background-attachement, but your question is not clear enough to make this worth an answer. **(answer i dleted earlier btw)**

Comment: there are vh (viewport height) and vw (viewport width) units you can use instead of px. 50vw = 50% of the viewport width

Comment: @G-Cyr yes, thanks for your support, I uploaded the code and an image to try and explain myself better, hope this explains what Im trying to achieve

Comment: okay, looks like background-attachement : https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pMreao same image used but with different colors , you can play with it and your own images https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pMreao unless i still misunderstand

Comment: @G-Cyr thanks, yes that works, it was what I was looking for, If you wana post it as an answer to mark it as answered I'd be happy to do it

Answer (score 2):

You might be looking for [`background-attachement:fixed`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-attachment).

> The `background-attachment` CSS property sets whether a background image's position is fixed within the viewport, or scrolls with its containing block.

test example

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 150vh;
  background: 
    linear-gradient(to right, transparent 1vw, yellow 1vw, yellow 24vw, transparent 24vw), 
    linear-gradient(to bottom, transparent 10vmin, rgba(255,255,255,0.7) 10vmin ,  rgba(255,255,255,0.7) calc(20vmin + 100px) ,  rgba(100,50,0,0) calc(20vmin + 100px)) ,
    url(http://dummyimage.com/250x100/055/fff;)0 0 fixed;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

div {
  float:left;
  margin: 15vmin 0 0 2.5vw;
  height: 80vh;
  width: 20vw;
  background: url(http://dummyimage.com/250x100/055/fff) 0 0 fixed;
}
div + div {
  height:100px;
  width:71vw
}
```

```html
<div> <p>NAV here</p></div>
<div> <p>NAV or there</p></div>
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!